# Div visibility in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

i was working on some requirements of my project and one of the requirement was to hide/unhide a Div on client side(Project is in .net technology and div's visibility will be set on client side using JS)

Code Snippet:

```
var block = document.getElementById('Your_Div_Id');
block.style.display = "none";   //some where it works to hide
block.style.visibility = "hidden";   //some where it works to hide
```

my question is why?

This is just hit and trial. first one was not working in one place so I used second one.I could not got to know why...

Comment: Could you please restate your actual question?

Comment: not sure why your browser does not like the first one. Just try the following and you can see Display None removes the element completely and makes the elements below to move up http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_display2

Comment: Double check the actual ID of the div, by viewing the page source in the web browser. ASP.net webforms can be great at taking the ID of a server control and making it something comletely differnt on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that display: none and visibility: hidden are different.
The first one "delete" the node from the DOM, and the other nodes can take it place.
The second one just hide hide, but the node preserves it position and sizes.

Tip: Try to use jQuery

```
$("#foo").hide();
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love jQuery. Using it just for this is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

In case you dont want to use jQuery, Make sure your Id of element is unique and is set properly in javascript code

you may also try writing the code in one line as below :

```
document.getElementById("element-id").style.display="none";
```